# Atomのatom-runnerで実行の中断ができない

Tags: python, atom-editor

環境
macOS Sierra(10.12.3)
atom 1.22.0
atom-runner 2.7.1
Python 3.5.1

Pythonの実行にatomのatom-runnerを利用しているのですが、例えば下記のプログラムの実行中にctl+shift+cを押しても実行を中断してくれません。

```
for i in range(1,100000):
　　print(i)
```

他のプログラムでも試しましたが、同様に中断はされませんでした。
正確に言えば、上記のプログラムだと実行中にctl+shift+cを押しても、99999まで表示して、実行終了の状態にならないようです。
ですが、実行が正常に終了した状態でctl+shift+cを押すとコンソールに^Cと表示されるみたいです。

ご回答頂けたら幸いです。

2017/11/09　追記
公式のGitHubを確認してみたら、同様のバグを報告している方がいらっしゃいました。

[Ctrl+Shift+C can not kill a running process on Mac](https://github.com/lsegal/atom-runner/issues/202)

色々試しつつ修正を待ちたいと思います。
コメントありがとうございました。

Comment: atom-runnerなのかscript-runnerなのか、どちらを信じたらいいんでしょう?

Comment: 申し訳ありません。ごっちゃになってましたね。修正しました。atom-runnerの方です。ちなみにctl+cでも止まりませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atom-Runner なら ctl+shift+c
Script-Runner rなら ctrl+c が正解です。

そこの勘違いではないでしょうか?

Comment: 本当だ。再現できました。確かにctl+shift+cで止まらないです。ですが、script-runnerで1回実行しておくと、なぜかatom-runnerがctl+shift+cで止まるようになります。回答の前に停止が確認できたのはそのためでした。これはバグかもしれないですね。

Comment: 公式のGitHubを確認してみたら同じような報告をしている人がいらっしゃったのでバグみたいですね。